# adding data to xml using php

Tags: php, xml, forms

have a form that a name has been entered and need to add it to xml file.

index.html

```
<form name="form" action="insert.php" method="post"> 

<label for="name">Name:</label> <br />  
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br />

<button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button> 
<br />
<span id="validate"></span>
</form>
```

insert.php

```
    header('Location:index.php'); 

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmldoc->load('recentUploads.xml'); 

$Name = $_POST['name']; 

$root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

$fileName = $xmldoc->createElement('name'); 

$root->appendChild($fileName); 

$newText1 = $xmldoc->createTextNode($Name);

$fileName->appendChild($newText1); 

$xmldoc->save('recentUploads.xml');
```

but i can not add anything to the xml file?

Help!

Comment: You're already *adding*, you're just missing the final [DOMDocument::save](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.save.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing a lot of burden on poor variable `$fileName`:

```
$fileName = $_POST['name']; 
$fileName = $xmldoc-> createElement('name');
```

On the other hand, `$Name` is not defined when you use it in line

```
$newText1 = $xmldoc->createTextNode($Name);
```

Me thinks these two incidents are related and one `$fileName` should actually be a `$Name`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php

Are you remembering to save() it back?

I don't see that in your example code...

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to call $xmldoc->saveXML();?

Comment: saveXML() returns a string. I assume the poster is looking to save it back to the file, so it would be the $xmldoc->save() method.